# Extracting text from a string after 5 characters and without the last slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a few strings:

```
some-text-123123#####abcdefg/
some-STRING-413123#####qwer123t/
some-STRING-413123#####456zxcv/
```

I would like to receive:

```
abcdefg
qwer123t
456zxcv
```

I have tried regexp:

```
/[^#####]*[^\/]/
```

But this not working...

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by after 5 characters

Comment: Try: `/#####([^\/]+)/`

Comment: Avoid regex when possible. How about `str.split("#####")[1].slice(0, -1)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get whatever comes after five `#`s and before the last `/`, you can use

```
/#####(.*)\//
```

and pick up the first group.

Demo:

```js
const regex = /#####(.*)\//;

console.log('some-text-123123#####abcdefg/'.match(regex)[1]);
console.log('some-STRING-413123#####qwer123t/'.match(regex)[1]);
console.log('some-STRING-413123#####456zxcv/'.match(regex)[1]);
```

Comment: You could also use lookaheads and lookbehinds to be able to exclusively match the string between them, without matching the `#####` or the `/`; i.e. `/(?<=#####).*(?=\/)/`

Comment: @Lemondoge although that would probably slow down the match.

Answer (score 2):

**assumptions:**

- the desired part of the string sample will always:

  - start after 5 `#`'s
  - end before a single `/`

**suggestion:** `/(?<=#{5})\w*(?=\/)/`

So `(?<=#{5})` is a lookbehind assertion which will check to see if any matching string has the provided assertion immediately behind it (in this case, 5 `#`'s).

`(?=\/)` is a lookahead assertion, which will check ahead of a matching string segment to see if it matches the provided assertion (in this case, a single `/`).

The actual text the regex will return as a match is `\w*`, consisting of a character class and a quantifier. The character class `\w` matches any alphanumeric character (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`). The `*` quantifier matches the preceding item 0 or more times.

**successful matches:**

- 'some-text-123123#####**abcdefg**/'
- 'some-STRING-413123#####**qwer123t**/'
- 'some-STRING-413123#####**456zxcv**/'

---

I would highly recommend learning Regular Expressions in-depth, as it's a very powerful tool when fully utilised.

MDN, as with most things web-dev, is a fantastic resource for regex. Everything from my answer here can be learned on [MDN's Regular expression syntax cheatsheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet).

Also, an interactive tool can be very helpful when putting together a complex regular expression. [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) is typically what I use, but there are many similar web-tools online that can be found from a google search.

Answer (score 1):

You pattern does not work because you are using [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`

The pattern `[^#####]*[^\/]` can be written as `[^#]*[^\/]` and matches optional chars other than `#` and then a single char other than `/`

---

Here are some examples of other patterns that can give the same match.

At least 5 leading `#` chars and then matching 1+ word chars in a group and the `/` at the end of the string using an anchor `$`, or omit the anchor if that is not the case:

```
#####(\w+)\/$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kr1Nrm/1)

If there should be a preceding character other than `#`

```
[^#]#####(\w+)\/$
(?<!#)#####(\w+)\/$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJ6dIY/1)

Matching at least 5 `#` chars and no `#` or `/` in between using a negated character class in this case:

```
#####([^#\/]+)\/
```

Or with lookarounds:

```
 (?<=(?<!#)#####)[^#\/]+(?=\/)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0MX5br/1)